# I can't mount KVM Virtual Disk '.qcow2' from other Linux Live CD to chroot invalid argument

Tags: virtual-machine, centos, mount, linux-kvm

Hi I have Linux `CentOS 7` I create it using `Virt-Manger` , I boot-up and Linux Distro Live CD [Tiny-core](http://tinycorelinux.net/) 9 to experiment with Linux shell and distro modification `chroot`

I list detected V disks with `fdisk -l` and my CentOS VD were `/dev/vda2` and the type shown `Linux LVM`
I tried to mount it with `sudo mount /dev/vda2 /mnt/disk1` I got this error
`mount: mounting /dev/vda2 on  /mnt/disk1 failed: invalid argument`

Comment: Have you tried another live distro?

Comment: No I'll try LinuxMint and see

Comment: @ajgringo619 I tried Fedora workstation and it did works, thanks for the hint you can post your comment as answer so i can select it .

Comment: I was just guessing, so I'm glad it worked. It's probably something that wasn't compiled in **Tiny-core's** kernel that standard distros have.

Comment: Yeah **Tiny-core's** are not reliable for such workload .